# Homebrew: "curl: (60) SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: macos, curl

I was trying to install Homebrew and then Tensorflow on my Mac. After typing the following command

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

(from [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)) to the terminal, I got the following error message:

> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
>
> More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

**Update:** The Mac version is OS X El Capitan 10.11.5

---

ps. I would really appreciate if you could provide me a solution with some explanation. This is the first time I use a Mac OS.

Comment: On which version of Mac OS are you?

Comment: It's OS X El Capitan 10.11.5

Comment: Ok, try with `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSLk https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Comment: I saw the -k suggestion, but tried to put it as "-e-k". Thank you.

Comment: i found it much easier to set up tensorflow on mac using miniconda instead of homebrew.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that your curl encountered a few issues with the certificate validation. You can skip it by enabling the `-k` option:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSLk https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: But why would `raw.githubusercontent.com` give him cert problems? Skipping the check hides the problem, it doesn't really fix them. Surely other users on this mac os version don't have the same problem?

Comment: @DanielStenberg it's not a fix, it's indeed a workaround, a possible cause may be OP's clock set to year 2001 (for example)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with git after upgrading to High Sierra.
These steps solved it for me:

1. Visit the website that is causing problems in Safari.
2. Look at the details of the certificate (especially the items higher up in the trust chain).
3. Open Keychain Access, find those certificates.
4. For each one, expand the "Trust" section and select "Always Trust" (only if you really do trust them of course ;-))

That solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just manually download the file
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh
on your downloads and then in the terminal

make sure the homebrew diretory is there

```bash
cp Downloads/install.sh /opt/homebrew

cd /opt/homebrew
```

after that make it executable

```bash
chmod +x install.sh
```

run it

```bash
/bin/bash -c ./install.sh
```

or

```bash
/bin/bash -e ./install.sh
```

and have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same symptoms and spent the whole day digging around. Turned out my `curl` was broken because `HTTPS_PROXY` was set to something else.

My solution was
`export HTTPS_PROXY=""`

Answer (score 1):

This issue is encountered when `curl`, internally used by `homebrew` is unable to verify the certificate using the Certificate Authorities that it uses for verification.

Instead of avoiding verification of certificates, preferred alternative would be to add the missing Certificate Authority (CA), to `homebrew` certificate store.

In my case my company uses Zscaler Private Access, which intercepts, encrypts and routes the internet traffic through Zscaler's network. The encrypted content can only be decrypted by Zscaler certificate which can be verified using Zscaler CA. This was resulting in `homebrew` failing with the error mentioned here.

To address this, I did couple of things:

1. Add Zscaler Root CA Certificate to homebrew's ca-certificates

```
cat Zscaler_Root_CA.crt >> /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/etc/ca-certificates/cert.pem
```

2. Configure homebrew to use its own ca-certificates as mentioned in [homebrew environment configuration](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#environment)

```
export HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CA_CERTIFICATES=1
```

Answer (score -1):

If anyone is finding the same problem running CURL from PHP, the equivalent to @Thomas Ayoub's answer is to use:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

It would still be great to find out if there's a way to update PHP's CA files (or whatever it needs) to pick up the certificates required.